# Unable to set context in an Enzyme test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using a method added to the context which is triggered in the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method.

I should be able to stub the context by providing an option to Enzyme's `shallow()` method, but this does not get passed to my component. For example:

My test:

```
it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const context = { dispatch: jest.fn() };

  shallow(<MyComponent />, { context });
});
```

and my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Consumer, Context } from '../../context';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  static contextType = Context;

  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.context; // dispatch is `undefined`

    dispatch({ type: 'BLAH', payload: 'blah' });
  }

  etc...

}
```

`this.context` is an object, but it has no properties - `dispatch` is always undefined.

Comment: Not a solution, but as a workaround I am disabling the lifecycle methods: `shallow(<MyComponent />, { context, disableLifecycleMethods: true });`

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, `enzyme` doesn't support `createContext` and `contextType` yet.

You can see its progress [here](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1553#issue-301920052).

Comment: is it still in progress ?

Answer (score 3):

This is quite hacky, but you can use existing support for the legacy API to test components that actually use the new API.

In your case, you can do the following in your test code:

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

MyComponent.contextTypes = {
    dispatch: PropTypes.any,
};
```

Now `shallow(<MyComponent />, { context });` should shallow render with your desired context value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use module [shallow-with-context](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shallow-with-context) than enzyme will support `contextType`.

Then your test can look like:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { withContext, createContext } from 'shallow-with-context';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const context = createContext({ dispatch: jest.fn() });
  const MyComponentWithContext = withContext(MyComponent, context);

  shallow(<MyComponent />, { context });
});
```